# Jquery - append element error

Tags: jquery, css, element, apply

Here is what i developed: http://jsfiddle.net/mSD72/80/ ,

I want you to type "abc" in the input-field, what you can see? :

A black quadrant appears on the upper left corner (of the body), but it should appear on the upper left corner of "map" !

This is the wrong code i think:

```
$("<p></p>").appendTo("map").css({
```

Anybody know´s which element to apply to? thanks and greetings!

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted.  You showed what you had tried, and tried explaining the problem you were facing.  Not sure why people jump to hit -1 instead of helping improve the question and find a solution.

Comment: It shows black boxes on my screen, so I do see something happen. And if that's why they downvoted, they should say so. I'm seriously sick of the anonymous downvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but you have the css set to be `position: absolute` which will start the coordinates (0,0) at the top left corner of the body.  Relative will start the coordinates (0,0) at the top left of their containing element.

Does changing it to relative do what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/kq64n/

```
            $("<p></p>").appendTo("map").css({
                "position" : "relative",
                "top" : dimensions[1] + "px",
                "left" : dimensions[0] + "px",
                "width" : "50px",
                "height" : "50px",
                "background-color" : "black"
            });
```

Comment: Just made you achieve 10K :)

Comment: @user3185975, glad it's sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

just because of your CSS definition (position: absolute) on JavaScript code.

Change it to "relative"

```
$("<p></p>").appendTo("map").css({
                "position" : "relative",
                "top" : dimensions[1] + "px",
                "left" : dimensions[0] + "px",
                "width" : "50px",
                "height" : "50px",
                "background-color" : "black"
            });
```

Absolute means if you define top or left etc. It will calculate the measure from window. But if you define it as relative, it appears parent tag as you define for top and left